# Wordpress - Category Post Order

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for some advice on what plugin I could use to allow my client to choose the order of posts in a catergory.

I have found plugins that allow a user to change the order but not the order of posts that are assigned to a category.

Has anyone got any good suggestion on this type of functionality?

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also you could find your question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I won't read that but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make simple filter witht `pre_get_posts`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts